# Calculate total sum from all prices items

Tags: java, android, listview

I have a `ListView` with 3 `TextViews` columns where I can click one of them and appear a `DialogAlert` and choose quantity.

When choose quantity from `AlertDialog` my price for specific product is multiply with number quantity.

Now, problem is I want in my `ListVIew` to make a `Total` for all products, I can't figure it out how to **calculate total** for products when quantity is changed.

**`My adapter :`**

```
public class VanzatorProduseList extends ArrayAdapter<VanzatorProduse> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList;
    private double total = 0.0;


    public VanzatorProduseList(Activity context, List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, vanzatorProduseList);
        this.context = context;
        this.vanzatorProduseList = vanzatorProduseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, null, true);
        final TextView textViewProdus1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus1);
        final TextView textViewPret1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret1);
        final TextView textViewCantitate1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCantitate1);
        final VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = vanzatorProduseList.get(position);
        textViewProdus1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
        textViewPret1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getPret());
        textViewCantitate1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                final ElegantNumberButton elegantNumberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.elegantNumberButton);
                final Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Alege cantitate : " + vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
                final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                b.show();
                dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
                        total = (Integer.parseInt(vanzatorProduse.getPret()) * (Integer.parseInt(num)));
                        textViewPret1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                        textViewCantitate1.setText(num);
                        b.dismiss();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Hope you can understand my question, I really have some serious problem with this problem and even if I looked for lots of tutorials, nothing happened.

Comment: Can't you loop on the list of child and sum the values ? It's hard to understand your problem and there is no update listener in your given code neither

Comment: yeah i know is pretty messy. i tried to loop but it didn't work properly

Comment: Could you put your class where you want to put the total?

Comment: i just want to display it in a Toast, that's what you mean ?

Comment: do you want to display the total of all your products inside your adapter? which is the button to fire that event?

Comment: here :  dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick

Comment: ok that is the button to change the quantity and update the subtotal, right? now you have the subtotal updated , but where do you want to display the total of all your products? which layout field?

Comment: in layout from the listview

Comment: I can't understand, would be fine if you put a screenshot of your UI to see what you need

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159586/discussion-between-diegoveloper-and-clau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first, add a new field in your `VanzatorProduse` class with set/get method:

```
public class VanzatorProduse {

int subTotal;

public int getSubTotal(){
    return subTotal;
}

public void setSubTotal(int subTotal){
    this.subTotal = subTotal;
}
}
```

Next, modify your Adapter :

```
public class VanzatorProduseList extends ArrayAdapter<VanzatorProduse> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList;
    private double total = 0.0;


    public VanzatorProduseList(Activity context, List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, vanzatorProduseList);
        this.context = context;
        this.vanzatorProduseList = vanzatorProduseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, null, true);
        final TextView textViewProdus1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus1);
        final TextView textViewPret1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret1);
        final TextView textViewCantitate1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCantitate1);
        final VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = vanzatorProduseList.get(position);
        textViewProdus1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
        textViewPret1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getPret());
        textViewCantitate1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
                final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_alert, null);
                dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
                final ElegantNumberButton elegantNumberButton = (ElegantNumberButton) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.elegantNumberButton);
                final Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_btn);
                dialogBuilder.setTitle("Alege cantitate : " + vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
                final AlertDialog b = dialogBuilder.create();
                b.show();
                dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String num = elegantNumberButton.getNumber();
                        total = (Integer.parseInt(vanzatorProduse.getPret()) * (Integer.parseInt(num)));
                        textViewPret1.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                        textViewCantitate1.setText(num);
                        b.dismiss();

                          vanzatorProduse.setSubTotal(total);

                         Toast.makeText(context, "total : " + calculateTotal(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return listViewItem;
    }


    public int calculateTotal(){
        int total = 0;
        for(VanzatorProduse vanzator: vanzatorProduseList){
            total+=  vanzator.getSubTotal();
        }
        return total;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect and clean ! Thanks a lot :)